# Which class is suitable to play music file?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-sl-8.1

My app will get all music file from `KnownFolders.MusicLibrary`, which will return `StorageFile`, but later I found out there's few Class I can choose to play music file.

What I want is that when I play a list of music file, it can be controlled on the universal volume control (like picture below).

I found `BackgroundAudioPlayer` Class, `BackgroundMediaPlayer` Class, `MediaPlayer` Class, and `MediaElement` Control. Which one of them is the most suitable Class/Control to play music file?

I'm developing Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it in the correct way (to allow users play music when your app is un background) you should use backgroundaudioplayer. I used it on Fildo and works great.

Comment: will the music keep on playing when app closed?

Comment: Yes because you launch it on a background service which is managed by system. You could implement it as you want, in my case I have a list of songs and play it randomly. 

Also you could get an event when a song ends to play the next one, etc.